No DbContext was found in assembly 'main_frame'
I want to connect to my SQLite database in C# but got an error that there was not enough migration. I installed Microsoft package.EntityFrameworkCore to include these commands:

Add-Transfer
Deleting-databases
Getting a DbContext
Scaffold-DbContext
Migration Script
Updating the database

But when using add-migration I get:

"Both Entity Framework Core and Entity Framework 6 are installed. The Entity Framework Core tools are running. Use 'EntityFramework\Add-Migration' for Entity Framework 6. No DbContext was found in assembly 'main_frame'. Ensure that you're using the correct assembly and that the type is neither abstract nor generic."

No matter how I call various commands, there is an error with DbContext.
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Data.Entity;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace main_frame
{
    internal class ApplicationContext : DbContext
    {
        public DbSet<All_Info> All_Info { get; set; }
        public ApplicationContext() : base("DefaultConnection") { }
    }
}

I installed various libraries and changed the configurator. Nothing worked.
PM> add-migration first
Both Entity Framework Core and Entity Framework 6 are installed. The Entity Framework Core tools are running. Use 'EntityFramework6\Add-Migration' for Entity Framework 6.
Build started...
Build succeeded.
No DbContext was found in assembly 'main_frame'. Ensure that you're using the correct assembly and that the type is neither abstract nor generic.
PM>


look at here https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/get-started/overview/first-app?tabs=visual-studio

Probably needs to be public.

How are you calling/using add-migration ? with Nuget Package Manager Console, terminal, powershell ... Provide the command or a screenshot. And also tell us about your project structure, there could be issues if you have a separate DataAccess project.

@terodaktil I edit my post. Now u can see that I used the Nuget Package Manager Console. And I have everything in one project with a local database because I use SQLite(If I understood the question correctly)

@Ihdina i follow your link but i got same problem on step: "Create the database" correctly on "Add-Migration InitialCreate"

@OUTWEST If you are using Entity Framework Core exclusively, it's recommended to remove any Entity Framework 6 references from your project to avoid conflicts.

@OUTWEST Right click on your project then select sync namespace to automatically update namespace

@OUTWEST  I followed Microsoft's example as in the link above and was successful without errors. Make sure you select Console App with Target Framework:: NET 8.0.

@OUTWEST If you select Console App (.Net Framework), an error will appear when  you install the library from nuget.

@OUTWEST If you are on the https://www.nuget.org/, look at the bottom where it says Frameworks, and in the version section it is blue button (for example it says .NET 8), then the project in VS2022 must use .NET 8, if you use .Net Framework then an error will appear during installation library from nuget.

@Ihdina I took your advice and removed entity framework 6 and I was able to do the migration, but now my project ends immediately at startup

@OUTWEST https://github.com/ctechid/EFGetStarted/archive/refs/heads/master.zip
